# mvn compile -> Error No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: java, maven, компиляция

Хочу запустить проект через командную строку

```
mvn compile
```

но получаю ошибку:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.095 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-22T14:35:57+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project test: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

В проекте есть pom.xml

```
<project>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Если запукаю через IDE все компилирется нормально
из консоли работает команда mvn -v:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T18:06:16+03:00)
Maven home: C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_161, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Как решить проблема?

Comment: Текст ошибки понятен? Вывод mvn -v понятен? Одно соответствует другому.

Comment: Так у вас не указано jre или jdk использовать при компиле

Comment: как его указать?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно указать в системе `JAVA_HOME` / `JRE_HOME`.

В зависимости от системы:

1. Windows 7 – My Computer > Properties > Advanced
2. Windows 8 – Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings
3. Windows 10 – в поисковике вбейте Environment Variables > Edit the system environment variables

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или через cmd (в примере - JDK. С JRE - аналогично):

```
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_XX"
```

Comment: переменные добавил, но команда mvn compile все равно не отрабатывает

Comment: @SerheosMorello переустановите jdk, скорее всего отсутствует папка lib

Comment: папка есть C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\lib

Comment: @SerheosMorello что у вас выводит при mvn -v?

Comment: да. через командную строку я могу получить версию мавена

Comment: вероятно, после добавления/изменения переменных окружения, запущенная консоль не видит изменений - консоль нужно закрыть и снова открыть